# how Suppress or solve windows cannot find ... make sure to type name correctly

Tags: windows, powershell, windowserror, startup-error

I have deleted the net limiter app , and yet every time i start my pc the error appears i also removed it form my startup section[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7vsB.png)

I have tried reinstalling the app but it did not work either
the image consists of the error message I get
I am also trying to scan for virus and updating my drivers .
please let me know of a solution or any way of suppressing the message thank u!

Comment: A shortcut exists in your startup menu that is still pointing to the removed application.  You just need to delete this shortcut.  You may run `del 'c:\users\pratik\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\netlimit*.lnk'` from powershell or delete through explorer.  To delete through explorer press Win+R to open run window.  Here type shell:startup and click OK.  In this folder you should see this netlimit shortcut.  Delete it.

Comment: i have deleted the shortcut yet i am getting the error

Comment: Maybe in the registry.  This link will show you where to look in the registry and you can delete the key.  https://www.akadia.com/services/windows_registry.html.  Also try Win+R and type shell:common startup, click OK.  Be sure it is not hiding in there as well.

Comment: Get `Sysinternals autoruns` software and find where it is running from